# Unity 3D Rigidbody 2D movement using MovePosition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Working on 2D mode, I have a script attached to a Sprite. The `Update()` part is as follow:

```
void Update () {
  if (Input.GetKeyDown ("left")) {
    cursor.rigidbody2D.MovePosition (cursor.rigidbody2D.position - speedX);
  } else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("right")) {
    cursor.rigidbody2D.MovePosition (cursor.rigidbody2D.position + speedX);
  } else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("up")) {
    cursor.rigidbody2D.MovePosition (cursor.rigidbody2D.position + speedY);
  } else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("down")) {
    cursor.rigidbody2D.MovePosition (cursor.rigidbody2D.position - speedY);
  }
}
```

where `cursor` is a Prefab linked in Inspector. The `cursor` prefab has only 2 components, Sprite Renderer (to define the image), and the Rigidbody 2D, which setting is as follow:

- Mass = 1
- Linear Drag = 0
- Angular Drag = 0
- Gravity Scale = 0
- Fixed Angle = true
- Is Kinematic = false
- Interpolate = None
- Sleeping Mode = Start Awake
- Collision Detection = Discrete

But when I press the arrow keys, the sprite showing on screen does not move. What did I miss?

Tried to add `Debug.Log()` inside the `if` case, it really enters the case. And no error occurred.

Note: `speedX = new Vector2(1,0);` and `speedY = new Vector2(0,1);`

Comment: Is `cursor` really linked with the prefab or with an instance of it? If it is linked with an object in your scene than the script should work.

Comment: It linked with a Prefab, dragged from Asset Library. How can I move a Prefab that does not appear on screen at the beginning? The above script is run after a `OnMouseDown()` event, which `Instantiate()` the Prefab on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to move an object that doesn't exist from the game's perspective. Assigning `cursor` a prefab by dragging it from the assets library, is like assigning a blueprint. Telling the prefab to move is like yelling at a car's blueprint to accelerate :)

There are two general solutions.

### 1) Save a reference

Instantiate the prefab and save the resulting reference to manipulate your new object. You can directly cast it to `Rigidbody2D` if you're mainly interested in using the rigidbody. The cast will only work if your prefab variable is of the same type, otherwise it will raise an exception. This way will ensure that your prefab always contains a `Rigidbody2D` or you can't even assign it in the editor.

```
public Rigidbody2D cursorPrefab; // your prefab assigned by the Unity Editor

Rigidbody2D cursorClone = (Rigidbody2D) Instantiate(cursorPrefab);
cursorClone.MovePosition (cursorClone.position - speedX);
```

### 2) Assign the script to the prefab

Depending on your game and what you want to achieve, you can also add a script directly to the prefab. This way every instance of it would just control itself.

```
void Update () {
  if (Input.GetKeyDown ("left")) {
    rigidbody2D.MovePosition (rigidbody2D.position - speedX);
  } else { //...}
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I'm really new in Unity. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The **1)** is almost perfect. The `Instantiate()` returns a `GameObject` and I extract the `Rigidbody2D` from the `GameObject`.

Comment: @Raptor Ah, I forgot to mention that `cursor` needs to be of type  `Rigidbody2D` for the cast to work. And don't forget to reassign it in the Unity Editor after changing a variable's type.